# On simulation run robot buries into ground plane

Tags: ros-humble, gazebo-8

I have a robot described in an xacro file that appears to spawn correctly in a world with a ground plane:

```
 <model name="ground_plane">
        <static>true</static>
        <link name="link">
            <collision name="collision">
                <geometry>
                    <plane>
                    <normal>0 0 1</normal>
                    </plane>
                </geometry>
            </collision>
            <visual name="visual">
                <geometry>
                    <plane>
                    <normal>0 0 1</normal>
                    <size>100 100</size>
                    </plane>
                </geometry>
                <material>
                    <ambient>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</ambient>
                    <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
                    <specular>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</specular>
                </material>
            </visual>
        </link>
    </model>
```

The bot has a chassis described in an xacro file like this:

```
<xacro:macro name="body" params="mass d h w *origin">
    <inertial>
        <xacro:insert_block name="origin"/>
        <mass value="${mass}" />
        <inertia 
            ixx="${(1/12) * mass * (h*h+w*w)}" 
            ixy="0.0"
            ixz="0.0"
            iyy="${(1/12) * mass * (d*d+w*w)}" 
            iyz="0.0"
            izz="${(1/12) * mass * (d*d+h*h)}" />
    </inertial>
</xacro:macro>
```

And then the chassis is defined as:

```
<link name="base_link_back">
<xacro:body mass="0.00001" d="0.0000010" h="0.000003" w="0.00003">
  <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0"/>
</xacro:body>
</link>

<joint name="base_link_back_joint" type="fixed">
<parent link="base_link"/>
<child link="base_link_back"/>
<origin rpy="0 0.0 3.14" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
</joint>

<link name="chassis">
<xacro:body mass="0.360" d="0.125" h="0.028" w="0.1256">
  <origin xyz="0 0.014 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
</xacro:body>
<collision>
  <origin rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" xyz="0 0.018 0"/>
  <geometry>
    <box size="0.1 0.015 0.1"/>
  </geometry>
</collision>

<visual>
  <origin rpy="0.0 3.14 0.0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
  <geometry>
    <mesh filename="$(find rae_description)/urdf/models/RAE-TOP-ASSY_0417.STL" scale="1.0 1.0 1.0"/>
  </geometry>
  <material name="mat">
    <lighting>1</lighting>
    <color rgba="0.1 0.1 0.1 1.0"/>
    <shader type='pixel'/>
    <emissive>0 0 0 1</emissive>
  </material>
  <transparency>0</transparency>
  <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
</visual>

</link>

<joint name="base_chassis_joint" type="fixed">
<parent link="base_link"/>
<child link="chassis"/>
<origin rpy="1.57 0.0 1.57" xyz="-0.0307 0.0 0.0" />
</joint>
```

The wheels have been commented out so this is just the chassis.

When gz is run, the chassis hovers above the ground plane, but when I play the sim, the chassis drops down to where half of the bot is below the ground plane (which prevents the wheels from touching the ground plane).

Could this be a spawning issue or am I missing a setting?